# Calculator does not take into account the priority of operations

Tags: perl

Here is a simple code. It must be slightly modified to take into account the priority of operations, but I can not figure out what to fix.

`

```
print "\nEnter the expression: ";

chomp($_ = <>);

print "\n";

sub mul {return $1*$2;}
sub div {return $1/$2;}
sub sum {return $1+$2;}
sub dif {return $1-$2;}

while(
     s/([+-]?\d+)\s*[*]\s*([+-]?\d+)/mul($1,$2)/e  || 
     s/([+-]?\d+)\s*[\/]\s*([+-]?\d+)/div($1,$2)/e || 
     s/([+-]?\d+)\s*[+]\s*([+-]?\d+)/sum($1,$2)/e  || 
     s/([+-]?\d+)\s*[-]\s*([+-]?\d+)/dif($1,$2)/e  || 
     s/\(\s*([+-]?\d+)\s*\)/$1/e
      )

{print "$_\n";}

print "\nThe ansver = $_\n";
```

`

I will be glad to have helped, thank you.

Comment: Who will have been helped by your post?

Comment: Looks like a homework problem to me.

Comment: Check out the dispatch table section of Higher Order Perl http://hop.perl.plover.com/book/.

Comment: Do you have an example input where it fails?  It keeps working OK for the input I give it.

Comment: it fails with (1*2)+3*(4+5) for example.

Comment: It will have to be **completely** rewritten to take into account order of operations. http://jeffreykegler.github.com/Ocean-of-Awareness-blog/individual/2012/dsl.html

Answer (score 3):

If you decide to use [Parse::RecDescent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parse%3a%3aRecDescent) (or any other LL parser), I suggest you read [Operator Associativity and Eliminating Left-Recursion in Parse::RecDescent](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=553889).

Answer (score 2):

You should really consider transforming the input to some kind of syntax tree. It will ease your problems. Shunting-yard-algorithm springs to mind.